# form onsubmit button fancybox not close

Tags: php, joomla, fancybox-2, virtuemart, joomla-k2

i'm using fancybox for form (in joomla 2.5 using virtuemart 2.0.18), I have a form when user clicks on buy now button the fancybox opens, and when clicks on submit button to submit the form the value successfully added to the cart but within the fancybox and next page opens in this fancybox, i don't want to open the next window in this same fancy box,

http://www.dextersoftwarelab.com/index.php/web-design-development/custom-web-development

I want when user click on submit button the fancy box close

firebug is showing me these errors

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'vm2front' 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 13143

---

SCRIPT5009: 'Hash' is undefined 
modal.js, line 7 character 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must have the JavaScript conflict